# Java - selenium compilation error "cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i got this in my code :

```
 mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
 wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Long.parseLong(getData("WaitTime")));
```

but i keep getting this compilation problem:

```
1) mainWindowHandle cannot be resloved to a variable
2) wait cannot be resolved to a variable
```

i have the import of:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

why i keep get this compilation error?

Comment: Probably because you never declared these variables anywhere. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: Where did you declare them? Post a complete minimal example reproducing it. We can't explain why your code is wrong without seeing it.

Comment: you right!  i removed them and not the import ones by accident..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

error like ***"cannot be resloved to a variable"*** occurs when you didn't defined variable type such as primitive or non-primitive. In your case, do as below

```
 String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Long.parseLong(getData("WaitTime")));
```